# Allow someone else to delete my Google Photos

Tags: images, file-sharing, sharing, google-photos

I went with my gf on a trip, photographs are saved in Google Photos. I've cleaned them, but there are some she wants to decide before deleting on her own time.

We are together, we really prefer not to spend time on our phones.

Is there a way to allow her to delete photographs that belong to my Google Photos account?

Failed attempt: Created shared album, put the photographs there, but she can't delete them.

PS: posted on travelexchange, and they suggested transferring the question here, hope it's ok.

Comment: Not without giving her access to your Google account.  There may be some very convoluted way of using the Google Photos API and re-uploading the photos to a new album via the API, but I can't see it being an easy path for you unless you are experienced with Google Apps Script.  [See this repository](https://github.com/tanaikech/GPhotoApp "GitHub: tanaikech/GPhotoApp")

Comment: You mean to all my Google account or just the Photos? @blindspots Either way, I think you should convert your comment to an answer, since this is the best I got.

Comment: Your actual account :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BlindSpots commented: Not without giving her access to your actual Google account. There may be some very convoluted way of using the Google Photos API and re-uploading the photos to a new album via the API, but I can't see it being an easy path for you unless you are experienced with Google Apps Script.  See this [repository](https://github.com/tanaikech/GPhotoApp).